# Sencha overlay has no background

Tags: sencha-touch

Im writing a Sencha touch app that I want to show a popup box that has three buttons.  I put a function in a controller that is supposed to display the popup, which it kind of does.  My problem is that there is no background or border for the popup, so you can see right through it.  Here is an example for my controller

```
Ext.regController('LoginController', {

 'login' : function(options) {
        loginPopup = new Ext.Panel({
            floating: true,
            modal: true,
            centered: true,
            width : 250,
            height : 250,
            layout : {
                align : "center",
                pack : "center"
            },
            styleHtmlContent : true,
            items : [Button1, Button2, Button3],
            dockedItems : [
                {
                    dock : 'top',
                    xtype : "toolbar",
                    title : 'Title'
                }
            ]
loginPopup.show('pop');
```

All the items and dockeditems show up, but there is no background or border.

I would have posted a pic, but im apparently not reputable

Comment: What is the CSS you are using?

Comment: Todd.....THANK YOU!!!  I was using a "sencha-touch.css" file that was provided to me by someone else.  I switched to the sencha-touch.css that is in the 1.1 download and it worked fine.  Thanks for you help!  I'm willing to give you credit if you post an answer, lol not really sure how this is supposed to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sencha-touch.js and sencha-touch.css from same version of Sencha Touch. js and css files are different for every version of Sencha Touch. For development, import the whole Sencha release. See [this](http://www.sencha.com/learn/hello-world/). For prod keep only files that you require.

Answer (score 0):

set background color for the overlay using the style property

```
style: 'background-color: color_of_your_choice'
```